# How to use ssh-key auth using vscode and the included ssh-keygen feature in windows 10?

Tags: git, powershell, visual-studio-code, ssh-keys, openssh

VSCode, Visual studio and Powershell are all unable to do git request using SSH-Key Auth when using the built in SSH-Client in Windows 10.

Git works fine when running commands from the command line, and if I start vscode from cmd line then that also works.

I have run the SSH -T command from powershell and this will return a success message with my username so the connection from powershell appears to be working. However doing any git request I get the following error:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

I have tried reinstalling git, re-creating the SSH-keys and turned on the SSH-Agent service and added the key once that was running.

None of the above worked.

I would like to avoid using as many programs as I can, such as putty and pageant.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should try to follow these steps:

- In your project folder run start-ssh-agent
- Add your id_rsa or whatever name of your private RSA key password
- In the same directory open the cmd or power shell and run code